# Mysql datediff for datetime types

Tags: mysql

I was wondering which of the following is the preferred way to use datediff for datetime types.

1. `datediff(current_date, <datetime type>)`
2. `datediff(current_date, date(<datetime type>))`
3. `datediff(now(), <datetime type>)`

I tried them out on a few cases and they all returned the same answer but I'm worried that they may produce some error down the line.

Is datediff the correct way to find the number of days between two datetime types?

Comment: Thank you both for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

- `datediff` internally casts parameters to date
- `now()` cast to a date is the same as `current_date`

There should be no difference in the result between any of those combinations

Answer (score 1):

For your purposes, they are all equivalent.

current_date returns a DATE type, while now() returns DATETIME

This doesn't matter in this case, though, because datediff() ignores the time part of a DATETIME, so using DATE and DATETIME with datediff() are completely equivalent.

Comment: I am using MYSQL version `5.5.47` and `datediff()` is *not* ignoring the time. If I put the time earlier than this time, it adds an extra day. Remove it, it retracts it again. It calculates by the second. I'm currently looking for a way to make it ignore the time part.